# Plotting a function with a gamma evaluation

Tags: plot, graphs

I need your help in graphing some functions within a Latex document. Two or more curves need to be graphed within my report to be placed between two paragraphs. For example,

```
f1(x) =abs((Gamma(1/x) - 4x) /Gamma(x+1))

f2(x) =1/(x+2)^3
```

On the interval `[1,15]`

Labeling both of the curves and the x and y axis.

Edit. I tried the following code, but not working!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-plot} 
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 
\usepackage{pst-func} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
   
\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xlabel = \(x\),
        ylabel = {\(f(x)\)}, ] %Below the red parabola is defined 
\addplot [
        domain=1:15, 
        samples=100, 
        color=red, ] { gnuplot {=abs((Gamma(1/x) - 4x) /Gamma(x+1))}} ;
    \addlegendentry{\(f1\)} %Here the blue parabola is defined 
\addplot [
        domain=1:15, 
        samples=100, 
        color=blue,
        ]
        {1/(x+2)^3}; \addlegendentry{\(f2\)}
    
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, sorry, added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?  Run with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-plot} 
\usepackage{pst-math} 

\begin{document}    
    
\psset{yunit=2}
\begin{pspicture} (0,0)(10,5)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(10,5)[$x$,0][$f(x)$,90]    
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,plotpoints=500}
\psplot[linecolor=blue]{1}{10}{%    ABS((GAMMA(1/x) - 4*x)/GAMMA(x+1))}
    1 x div GAMMA 4 x mul sub x 1 add GAMMA div abs } 
\psplot[linecolor=red,yunit=5,algebraic]{1}{10}{1/(x+2)^3}
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great :) // How do you label both curves, see question?

Comment: @user187802, Thank you. I tried this code in overleaf but it's not working, did I miss something!

Comment: give a link to your overleaf example, so that I can try it